# How to use comparator in priority queue kotlin

Tags: kotlin, priority-queue

Hey I want to use custom comparator in priority queue in kotlin. I have data class

**Product.kt**

```
data class Product(val value: String? = null, val price: String? = null) {
    var priceInLong = price?.toLong()
}
```

I want to create a min heap where price value will be minimum. I am creating the object but it giving me some kind of error

```
fun main() {
    var queue = PriorityQueue<Long> { p1: Product, p2: Product ->
        p1.priceInLong?.let {
            p2.priceInLong?.minus(it)
        }
    }

    val list = listOf(
        Product("1", "4.83"),
        Product("2", "4.53"),
        Product("3", "3.54"),
        Product("4", "3.66"),
        Product("5", "5.16")
    )
}
```

**error**

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>((MutableCollection<out TypeVariable(E)!>..Collection<TypeVariable(E)!>?))   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    constructor PriorityQueue<E : Any!>(c: (MutableCollection<out E!>..Collection<E!>?)) defined in java.util.PriorityQueue
<init>(Comparator<in TypeVariable(E)!>!)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    constructor PriorityQueue<E : Any!>(comparator: Comparator<in E!>!) defined in java.util.PriorityQueue
<init>(PriorityQueue<out TypeVariable(E)!>!)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    constructor PriorityQueue<E : Any!>(c: PriorityQueue<out E!>!) defined in java.util.PriorityQueue
<init>(SortedSet<out TypeVariable(E)!>!)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    constructor PriorityQueue<E : Any!>(c: SortedSet<out E!>!) defined in java.util.PriorityQueue
<init>(Int)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    constructor PriorityQueue<E : Any!>(initialCapacity: Int) defined in java.util.PriorityQueue
```

image

[image]

> **1.** I want to solve this error and add value by price which is minimum comes first.

> **2.** Is my above **queue comparator** logic is correct to use min heap?

Thankss

**UPDATE**

I tried this suggestion

```
var queue = PriorityQueue<Product> { p1, p2 ->
        return if (p1.priceInLong != null && p2.priceInLong != null) {
            p2.priceInLong - p1.priceInLong
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
```

getting error

[image]

UPDATE 2

```
val queue = PriorityQueue<Product> { p1, p2 ->
        val priceOne = p1.priceInLong
        val priceTwo = p2.priceInLong
        if (priceOne != null && priceTwo != null) {
            if(priceOne == priceTwo){
                return 0 
            }
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

data class Product(val value: String? = null, val price: String? = null) {
    val priceInLong = price?.toLong()
}
```

[image]

Comment: How should be ordered `Products` without price (if `priceInLong==null`)?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь tbh I think we can leave that value then.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "leave that value"? If you put in a PriorityQueue a product with priceInLong=null and another one with priceInLong=1, which should come first?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь sorry my english is not good. The value with `priceInLong=1` comes first . I don't want any null value in my queue. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so it's somehow guaranteed there will be no products with priceInLong=null?

Comment: Yes @МихаилНафталь you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
{ p1: Product, p2: Product ->
        p1.priceInLong?.let {
            p2.priceInLong?.minus(it)
        }
}
```

returns **null** if `p1.priceInLong` is null (the `let` block isn't executed), or if `p2.priceInLong` is null (the `let` block returns null). That's what the null-safety checking with `?` does.

You're getting the error because your `Comparator` function needs to return an `Int`, but yours returns `Int?`, i.e. a nullable int value - could be an int, could be null. So it doesn't match the required constructor, that's why it's complaining that none of the functions match.

So you need to decide what to do if one (or both) of those values are null, and return an integer instead of any nulls, so your function returns `Int` and not `Int?`

---

If what you're saying in the comments is correct, and neither of those values will ever be null, you can just assert that with `!!`

```
{ p1: Product, p2: Product ->
    p2.priceInLong!! - p1.priceInLong!!
}
```

But using `!!` is a bad sign - how do you know they'll never be null? If you can say that for sure, why is `priceInLong` nullable in the first place?

Comment: thanks for explaining me. If suppose my `p1` is null and `p2` has some value, I need to return the value. Can you please give example how to fix that problem.

Comment: @vivekmodi just do an ``if`` block or something - if both are null, return 0. If one is null and the other isn't, return a value (I'm assuming you'll want it to be positive or negative depending on **which one** is null). If neither are null, do the comparison

Comment: how now I understand can you give me example how can I not use `!!` operator. Like you suggesting to us if statment. Please?

Comment: i am trying your suggestion to use if else but it giving me error. Can you look in question, I updated there. Thanks

Comment: @vivekmodi I don't know how your code is structured or what you need it to do, you'll have to work it out for yourself! Your comparator needs to return *a negative number* if *1st < 2nd*, *zero* if *1st = 2nd*, or a *positive number* if  *1st > 2nd*- you need to handle any cases where something is null, and decide what that means, and which result you need to return

Comment: @vivekmodi your new error is because ``priceInLong`` is a ``var`` so it could have changed after you null checked it. Can you make it a ``val``? If not, you need to copy it (``val price1 = p1.priceInLong`` etc) and use that copy for your null checks, comparisons etc

Comment: I used your suggestion and I tried. But it again giving me error. Can you please look and guide me what I am doing wrong there? I updated the section.

Comment: @vivekmodi You didn't specify what should happen if values are not null and they differ. Look, you can't expect people will do everything for you. You have to try by yourself.

Comment: @broot sorry. But I am trying code what people suggest. I really appreciate what people suggest to me. If values are not null then I want to store first minimum value. Thanks for suggestion. I am trying to learn the stuff. :(

Comment: @vivekmodi now your error is that you can't use ``return`` in a lambda, you need to just express a value, like ``if (priceOne == priceTwo) 0 ``, and there always needs to be a matching ``else`` so that you're always providing **some** value. Honestly, it seems like you're having trouble with Kotlin in general (I think you're new to it, right?) and that makes it hard to give you specific advice. We don't know what you're doing, we can only point you in the right direction, so you can work it out for yourself. We can't teach you the language as you go, y'know?

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for your great suggestion. Yes I am started learning kotlin in few months ago. I forgot that we cannot use return in lambda. I am thanks for everyone who supports for beginners. I know I need to work myself, only people can give. the right direction. Thanks for every helpful directions.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to solve this error

Two problems here:

1. Type argument of `PriorityQueue` should be a `Product` (if you want to store these objects in it).
2. Lambda of `Comparator` should return `Int`, not `Long?`. If it's guaranteed, that there will be no `Product`s with `priceInLong == null`, you may just use the not-null assertion operator to get rid of nullability and then get [sign](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/sign.html) of difference to avoid possible integer overflow of `.toInt()` conversion:

```kotlin
val queue = PriorityQueue<Product> { p1, p2 -> (p1.priceInLong!! - p2.priceInLong!!).sign }
```

Comment: How can I remove `!!` to operator. I don't want to take risk if my value is null then my application will give exception.

Comment: If you want to allow products with `priceInLong == null` to be put inside the queue, you need to define, how you want them to be sorted. If products with `priceInLong == null` should come first, then replace `priceInLong!!` with `(priceInLong ?: 0)`; otherwise - with `(priceInLong ?: Long.MAX_VALUE)`